# Lambda and Textract: start_document_text_detection unknown parameter "OutputConfig"

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-textract

I am trying to extract text from a PDF using a Lambda Function and Textract.

My question is:
**How can I call "start_document_text_detection" so that Textract automatically sends its response to S3?**

I get an error saying:

> [ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
> Unknown parameter in input: "OutputConfig", must be one of: DocumentLocation, ClientRequestToken, JobTag, NotificationChannel

My code:

```
    textract = boto3.client('textract')
    textract.start_document_text_detection(
      DocumentLocation={
          'S3Object': {
              'Bucket': origin_bucket,
              'Name': key
          }
      },
      JobTag=key + '_Job',
      OutputConfig={
        "S3Bucket": destination_bucket,
        "S3Prefix": key
      })
```

Boto3 Documentation shows that I can pass a parameter called "OutputConfig":
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/textract.html#Textract.Client.start_document_text_detection

```
response = client.start_document_text_detection(
    DocumentLocation={
        'S3Object': {
            'Bucket': 'string',
            'Name': 'string',
            'Version': 'string'
        }
    },
    ClientRequestToken='string',
    JobTag='string',
    NotificationChannel={
        'SNSTopicArn': 'string',
        'RoleArn': 'string'
    },
    OutputConfig={
        'S3Bucket': 'string',
        'S3Prefix': 'string'
    }
)
```

AWS Textract's official documentation also says it is a valid parameter:

> Another optional parameter available is **OutputConfig**, which lets you adjust where your output will be placed. By default, Amazon Textract will store the results internally, and can only be accessed by the Get API operations. With OutputConfig enabled, you can set the name of the bucket the output will be sent to, and its file prefix, where you can download your results as JSON. This allows for use of a user created bucket for storing results.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/api-async.html

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using an older version of boto3. Upgrading to the latest version (>1.16.36) should solve your problem.

Comment: I'm using the boto3 from AWS (I mean that I don't install any version of boto3 since it is available in the Lambda "environment"). I will try your idea and see if it works.

Comment: I checked the boto3 version in lambda, it is 1.20. But i am still getting the same error